# Rounded rectangle with stroke on top android drawable XML

Tags: android, xml, drawable, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I was trying to make a drawable using XML in android. The requirement is I need to have a rounded rectangle(all 4 corners rounded) with a stroke of 7dp height only on the top edge. I am using the following XML for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/theme_color" />
            <solid android:color="@color/theme_color" />
            <corners
                android:radius="7dp"/>
            <padding android:top="7dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/designer_cell_background" />
            <solid android:color="@color/designer_cell_background" />
            <corners
                android:radius="7dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"/>
            <padding android:bottom="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I am getting this working almost OK, except that the bottomRight and bottomLeft corners are not rounded.

Question - 1 : How to get the bottom corners rounded?

Question - 2 : Is this the correct way to achieve what I actually want? Is there a better way? I am asking this because, I understand what I do here is actually making two rectangles, one on top of another, the second one is being slightly lowered from the top edge of the first rectangle so that the color of the first rectangle appears as a line on top of the second one. And then adding corner radius to each rectangle individually. I don't think it is the right solution. But I failed when I tried to add a stroke of 7dp width to the top of a rounded rectangle. The stroke I gave was appearing on all the edges.

**EDIT**

Here is what I want:

[image: Expected Output]

And this is what I currently get:

[image: Actual Output]

Comment: can you post image what you want ??

Answer (score 3):

```
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

        <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />

        <corners android:radius="12dp" />

    </shape>
```

ur using the radius value increased curve shape wil increase

Comment: Nope.. I need the stroke only on the TOP edge, not on ALL edges.

Comment: if you need a stroke only on top edge it is no rectangle anymore but a horizontal line

Comment: use a nine patch drawable

Comment: @pskink You mean there is no way to get a simple drawable that contain a rounded rectangle with a line on top of it, other than using9patch drawable?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT of course no,  you can use a ShapeDrawable with custom Shape for example

Comment: @HarikrishnanT a custom Shape would be more or less ten lines of code

Comment: That would suffice. I need to decrease the apk size, so maximum small number of images. :)

Comment: @HarikrishnanT when using ShapeDrawable you don't use images at all

Answer (score 2):

try this is works let me know

this tool is helps me you can also get help from it

> http://angrytools.com/android/button/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/theme_color" />
        <solid android:color="@color/theme_color" />
        <corners
            android:radius="7dp"/>
        <padding android:top="7dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/designer_cell_background" />
        <solid android:color="@color/designer_cell_background" />

       <corners
           android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
           android:topRightRadius="0dp"
           android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
           android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"/> 

        <padding android:bottom="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: The link you provided appears to be helpful only for making basic drawable button. It can not be customized to what I require.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT use a nine patch drawable

Comment: @HarikrishnanT, Actually it can. A Button is just a View minus a couple of properties. Remove those properties, rename the parent class it uses, and the code will work just fine. Of course then, your app will look like an iPhone app, because rounded corners around a layout contradicts the Android UI design Guidelines, but I guess that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should create 2 shapes the black one and the red one, just overlay the other shape to become the image you're looking for. you can't accomplish that with one shape in android.